# jsprit how to add picked-up shipment to a vehicle

Tags: jsprit

I want to recover the VRP problem from a context.
In that context some vehicle might already loaded some shipments and en route of delivery. Or maybe it's going to the pickup location for pickup.

I don't want to re-assign those tasks to other vehicles. How can I assign them to the vehicles in that context?

My current workaround is set the picked-up very near to that vehicle's context location and a tight pickup window and a required skill to force the vehicle to pick it up. (this might not always work, so I need a hard writing way to do the set up)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try jsprit's initial route feature. You can refer to [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jsprit-mailing-list/QfXPKy1hcjM) in jsprit's old mailing list and [the example here](https://github.com/graphhopper/jsprit/blob/master/jsprit-examples/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/jsprit/examples/MultipleDepotWithInitialRoutesExample.java).

EDIT:

essential parts of the answer:

```
VehicleRoute initialRoute_withShipmentsAndServices = VehicleRoute.Builder.newInstance(vehicle3)
    .addPickup(shipment1).addPickup(shipment2)
    .addService(service3).addService(service4)
    .addDelivery(shipment2).addDelivery(shipment1)
    .build();

vrpBuilder.addInitialVehicleRoute(initialRoute_withShipmentsAndServices);
```

Comment: that's exactly what I'm looking for thank you! @He Huang